Docker Hadoop Installation Error: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset
I'm setting up a Hadoop environment using Docker and encountering an error during installation:
My setup:

Using Docker-compose.yml to configure multiple services (namenode, datanode, resourcemanager, nodemanager, Spark master/worker).

Docker-compose.yml excerpt:


version: '3'

services:
  namenode:
    image: apache/hadoop:3
    hostname: namenode
    command: [ "hdfs", "namenode" ]
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
    env_file:
      - ./config2
    environment:
      ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name"
      HADOOP_HOME: /opt/hadoop
      PATH: /opt/hadoop/bin:/opt/hadoop/sbin:$PATH
    volumes:
      - ./hadoop-entrypoint.sh:/hadoop-entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: ["/hadoop-entrypoint.sh"]

  datanode:
    image: apache/hadoop:3
    command: [ "hdfs", "datanode" ]
    env_file:
      - ./config2
    environment:
      HADOOP_HOME: /opt/hadoop
      PATH: /opt/hadoop/bin:/opt/hadoop/sbin:$PATH
    volumes:
      - ./hadoop-entrypoint.sh:/hadoop-entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: ["/hadoop-entrypoint.sh"]

  resourcemanager:
    image: apache/hadoop:3
    hostname: resourcemanager
    command: [ "yarn", "resourcemanager" ]
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    env_file:
      - ./config2
    environment:
      HADOOP_HOME: /opt/hadoop
      PATH: /opt/hadoop/bin:/opt/hadoop/sbin:$PATH
    volumes:
      - ./test.sh:/opt/test.sh
      - ./hadoop-entrypoint.sh:/hadoop-entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: ["/hadoop-entrypoint.sh"]

  nodemanager:
    image: apache/hadoop:3
    command: [ "yarn", "nodemanager" ]
    env_file:
      - ./config2
    environment:
      HADOOP_HOME: /opt/hadoop
      PATH: /opt/hadoop/bin:/opt/hadoop/sbin:$PATH
    volumes:
      - ./hadoop-entrypoint.sh:/hadoop-entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: ["/hadoop-entrypoint.sh"]

    spark-master:
      container_name: spark-master
      hostname: spark-master
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.spark
      command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
      volumes:
        - ./config:/opt/bitnami/spark/config
        - ./jobs:/opt/bitnami/spark/jobs
        - ./datasets:/opt/bitnami/spark/datasets
        - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
      ports:
        - "9090:8080"
        - "7077:7077"
      networks:
        - code-with-yu

    spark-worker: &worker
      container_name: spark-worker
      hostname: spark-worker
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.spark
      command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
      volumes:
        - ./config:/opt/bitnami/spark/config
        - ./jobs:/opt/bitnami/spark/jobs
        - ./datasets:/opt/bitnami/spark/datasets
        - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
      depends_on:
        - spark-master
      environment:
        SPARK_MODE: worker
        SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
        SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
        SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
      networks:
        - code-with-yu

  #  spark-worker-2:
  #    <<: *worker
  #
  #  spark-worker-3:
  #    <<: *worker
  #
  #  spark-worker-4:
  #    <<: *worker
  networks:
    code-with-yu:


Dockerfile.spark

FROM apache/hadoop:latest
FROM bitnami/spark:latest

COPY requirements.txt .

USER root

RUN apt-get clean  && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Using apache/hadoop:3 for Hadoop services and bitnami/spark:latest for Spark services.
Despite setting HADOOP_HOME in Docker-compose.yml, the error persists. How can I properly set HADOOP_HOME in this Docker environment? What might be causing this error?
Additional info:
OS: Windows 11
Docker version: 26.1.1
Docker-compose version:  v2.27.0-desktop.2
